# Create the equivalent of a detection file to use in Mask RCNN evaluate_model

Tags: python, json, list, numpy

I am trying to create the equivalent of a detection result file by Mask RCNN in matterport to evaluate the results created by another model but using Matterport [evaluation mechanism](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/3deaec5d902d16e1daf56b62d5971d428dc920bc/mrcnn/utils.py#L715).

When I print `yhat = model.detect(sample)` from the matterport detection module [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/1ad9feaae3d87b52495413e6c8ea0e92f0e5bc34/mrcnn/model.py#L2482)

I get

```
{'rois': array([[399, 116, 452, 178],
       [663, 608, 713, 669]]),
    'class_ids': array([1]),....}
```

I am trying to create the equivalence of the above file, How does he manage to get the keyword `array` before his values?

With the below code, I managed to get them without the keyword `array` before the values.

My results

```
{'rois': [[399, 116, 452, 178],
          [663, 608, 713, 669]]),
 'class_ids': [1], ...}
```

My code:

```
with open("samples.json", 'w') as f:

    data = []
    data.append({
        "rois": boxes,
        "class_ids": class_ids,
    })

    json.dump(data, f)
```

My question is, how do I change my code to get the same format `arrays` before the values similar to the Matterport output?

Passing my JSON directly returns

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8c720f8cc382> in <module>()
      6 
      7 # evaluate model on training dataset
----> 8 train_mAP = evaluate_model(train_set, cfg)

<ipython-input-13-628eaf4d7868> in evaluate_model(dataset, cfg)
     40 
     41         AP, _, _, _ = compute_ap(gt_bbox, gt_class_id, gt_mask, r["rois"], r["class_ids"], 
---> 42                                  r["scores"], gt_mask)
     43 
     44 

C:\Users\name\Desktop\Projects\PyCharm_Projects\6_maskRCNN\mrcnn\utils.py in compute_ap(gt_boxes, gt_class_ids, gt_masks, pred_boxes, pred_class_ids, pred_scores, pred_masks, iou_threshold)
    728         gt_boxes, gt_class_ids, gt_masks,
    729         pred_boxes, pred_class_ids, pred_scores, pred_masks,
--> 730         iou_threshold)
    731 
    732     # Compute precision and recall at each prediction box step

C:\Users\name\Desktop\Projects\PyCharm_Projects\6_maskRCNN\mrcnn\utils.py in compute_matches(gt_boxes, gt_class_ids, gt_masks, pred_boxes, pred_class_ids, pred_scores, pred_masks, iou_threshold, score_threshold)
    670     gt_boxes = trim_zeros(gt_boxes)
    671     gt_masks = gt_masks[..., :gt_boxes.shape[0]]
--> 672     pred_boxes = trim_zeros(pred_boxes)
    673     pred_scores = pred_scores[:pred_boxes.shape[0]]
    674     # Sort predictions by score from high to low

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\PyCharm_Projects\6_maskRCNN\mrcnn\utils.py in trim_zeros(x)
    650     x: [rows, columns].
    651     """
--> 652     assert len(x.shape) == 2
    653     return x[~np.all(x == 0, axis=1)]
    654 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Update:

`yhat = model.detect(sample)` is of type `<class 'dict'>`

Comment: What you're seeing is probably a numpy `array`. If you have numpy installed, you should be able to do `from numpy import array` and then just call `array()` on all your lists to turn them into arrays.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that returns `TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: `array` is not part of JSON syntax.

Comment: @MarkTolonen if I pass my JSON directly, I get  `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`. This made me assume I am missing the so-called `array` conversion. What are your tips?

Comment: @MarkTolonen `yhat` which is the output of the model is is of type `dict`....

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do.  Do you want to serialize `numpy.array` to and from JSON format?  To do that you would need a custom encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 1):

The first output is not JSON, it's just the way Python prints an array.
In JSON there is no array keyword or similar, an array is simply denoted by the `[..]`.
So if you where to create JSON from the first object and then printed that JSON, it would be identical, to what you created.

Comment: strange, because using my file returns `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use np.array right before passing to the `compute_ap`

```
   AP, _, _, _ = compute_ap(gt_bbox, gt_class_id, mask_gt, 
                                         np.array(r["rois"], dtype="float32"), 
                                         np.array(r["class_ids"], dtype="float32"), 
                                         np.array(r["scores"], dtype="float32"),
                                         mask_dt)
```